# How to create a horizontal bar plot from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a dataframe df - 
df-

```
    Source  Amount
1   University of Minnesota 119367000
2   Minnesota State Colleges and Universities   159812000
3   Education   7491000
4   Minnesota State Academies   11354000
5   Perpich Center for Arts Education   2000000
6   Natural Resources   63480000
7   Pollution Control Agency    2625000
8   Board of Water and Soil Resources   8000000
9   Agriculture 203000
10  Zoological Garden   12000000
11  Administration  127000000
12  Minnesota Amateur Sports Commission 7973000
13  Military Affairs    3244000
14  Public Safety   4030000
15  Transportation  57263000
16  Metropolitan Council    45968000
17  Human Services  86387000
18  Veterans Affairs    2800000
19  Corrections 11881000
20  Employment and Economic Development 92130000
21  Public Facilities Authority 45993000
22  Housing Finance Agency  20000000
23  Minnesota Historical Society    12002000
24  Bond Sale Expenses  900000
25  Cancellations   -10849000
26  TOTAL   893054000
27  Bond Proceeds Fund (General Fund Debt Servic... 814745000
28  Bond Proceeds Fund (User Financed Debt Servi... 39104000
29  State Transportation Fund   36613000
30  Maximum Effort School Loan Fund 5491000
31  Trunk Highway Fund  7950000
32  Bond Proceeds Cancellations -10849000
```

I want to create a horizontal barplot to plot this data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.barh(expense_df['Amount'],expense['Source'])
plt.show()
```

But the above piece of code gives and error - `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>`

How can i create a horizontal bar plot?

I have plotted the expected plot in excel - 
[image]

How can i recreate this in python?

Comment: Public data. 
source- https://www.revisor.mn.gov/laws/?year=2014&type=0&doctype=Chapter&id=294

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [`plot.barh`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.barh.html), but before [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`) and [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
#set index from column Source, remove index name
df = df.set_index('Source').rename_axis(None)
#sorting values
df = df.sort_values('Amount', ascending=False)
```

```
print df
                                                    Amount
TOTAL                                            893054000
Bond Proceeds Fund (General Fund Debt Service)   814745000
Minnesota State Colleges and Universities        159812000
Administration                                   127000000
University of Minnesota                          119367000
Employment and Economic Development               92130000
Human Services                                    86387000
Natural Resources                                 63480000
Transportation                                    57263000
Public Facilities Authority                       45993000
Metropolitan Council                              45968000
Bond Proceeds Fund (User Financed Debt Service)   39104000
State Transportation Fund                         36613000
Housing Finance Agency                            20000000
Minnesota Historical Society                      12002000
Zoological Garden                                 12000000
Corrections                                       11881000
Minnesota State Academies                         11354000
Bond Proceeds Cancellations                       10849000
Cancellations                                     10849000
Board of Water and Soil Resources                  8000000
Minnesota Amateur Sports Commission                7973000
Trunk Highway Fund                                 7950000
Education                                          7491000
Maximum Effort School Loan Fund                    5491000
Public Safety                                      4030000
Military Affairs                                   3244000
Veterans Affairs                                   2800000
Pollution Control Agency                           2625000
Perpich Center for Arts Education                  2000000
Bond Sale Expenses                                  900000
Agriculture                                         203000
```

```
df.plot.barh(figsize=(10,20))
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

Answer (score 2):

Boilerplate

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [2]: %matplotlib
Using matplotlib backend: Qt4Agg

In [3]: import pandas as pd
```

My fake data

```
In [4]: data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

In [5]: data
Out[5]: 
       Name   Value
0  asde rty     100
1   4 wewer     200
2   uwei ef     300
```

Now, the interesting part, first use dataframe methods to plot dataframe content,

```
In [6]: data.plot.barh()
Out[6]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x7facb0706198>
```

The above labels y-axis with 0, 1, 2, no good... so we have to modify the plotted object, first you have to grab the plotted object (`gca` stands for get current axis)

```
In [7]: ax = plt.gca()
```

then you tell, it's object oriented isn't it? you tell to the current axis to modify the y ticks labels, that is (unsurprisingly)

```
In [8]: ax.set_yticklabels(data['Name']);
Out[8]: 

In [9]:
```

and this is the output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I might be embarrassing myself here, but could it be that you need to feed a different type of data into matplotlib?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
expense_df = {'Amount' : 0, 'Amount' : 1, 'Amount' : 2}
expense = {'Source' : 1, 'Source' : 2, 'Source' : 3}

plt.barh(expense_df['Amount'],expense['Source'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Ryan, but that only plotted a blank blue screen

Comment: for me also :) have a bit of a play around with your data, your probably have to put it in a dict or an array before passing it to matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `plt.barh()` must be numerical and it does not look like `expense['Source']` is. I cannot provide a more concrete answer since I don't know what you want the widths of the bars to be, but obviously "University of Minnesota" is not a valid width.