# how to plot columnwise in pandas?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I make a DataFrame as below

[image]

I want to plot it as countplot like this

[image]

where hue to be column of my dataframe

Comment: Did you try `df.plot.barh()`?

Comment: Please (a) post your data as text not as an image so that other people can easily run it locally; and (b) post some code of what you have tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3.x - Horizontal bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36824433/python-3-x-horizontal-bar-plot)

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure what is the format of you table, if you use pd.crosstab like below, you can easily call plot.bar() to give you the plot you want:

```
import seaborn as sns
tab = pd.crosstab(np.random.choice(["very useful","somewhat useful","not useful"],1000),
                  np.random.choice(["test","kaggle"],1000))
tab.plot.barh()
```

[image]